# Changing main menu in Big Cartel Parade design and changing font size

Tags: html, bigcartel

not adept, but about enough to stumble through HTML/site backend (stumble and fall mostly). I had a Big Cartel site a few years back and it was really easy to modify with HTML. Anyway, I currently have a new site and it's nearly perfect for my needs, but just not for the following:

1. The main menu is great for 'Shop', About, Contact pages, but I would
   like to remove c. 5 pages to sit on the footer of the page, ie. T&C,
   Shipping, Care etc., (ideally with a border / different colour
   footer, but that might be stretching it.)
2. Secondly, the font size on the About etc page is huge. Again, it
   used to be user friendly to change that, but Big Cartel have
   obviously clamped down (which is a shame, as it's the best for a
   creative... or it was)

Any ideas where to start? Big Cartel seem reluctant to get involved in this side anymore.
Appreciate any suggestions!